# Cannot set value on a formControl from ngOnInit method

Tags: angular, angular-material

I took a Material Select example and tried to set a default value from the ngOnInit method like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.animalControl.setValue({name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'});
}
```

But it is not showing the default value in the select (there is only Meow). I do not know why.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hek85v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error here is not due to your `FormControl` not being populated correctly on `ngOnInit` but yet instead your ngFor filters through the list `animals: Animal[]` which have a different reference than your new object `{name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'}`, if you instead pass an object within your animal list it will have the correct reference and display the value of the animal name correctly.

Example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
this.animalControl.setValue({name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'});
```

set value of animalFormControl by calling animals array.
Update your code by reviewing below implementation

```
this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hek85v-esgqqz?file=main.ts)

> instead passing new object you have to pass your array data

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[0]);
  }
```